# SpecFlow test plan from features

Tags: bdd, specflow, test-plan

How to get a "test plan" from SpecFlow feature files? Is it possible to get similar "report" (HTML, pdf, word, etc.) as we get from executed tests?

It would be great to get table with:

- test description
- steps
- expected result

Information is already inside feature files, just how to structure it as "test plan"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean with "testplan" but using SpecFlow.exe you can get two kind of reports:

- A test execution report, that shows how your tests has executed. I've written about it here: http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/12/specflowexe-and-mstest.html
- A step definition report, that shows how the step definitions are used within your specifications. I've written about that here: http://www.marcusoft.net/2010/12/know-where-you-stepgenerate-step.html

Combining these two might give you what your looking for, but (!) I think what your actually looking for is something like SpecLog that is a tool to manage stories and requirements in an agile project.

I written about SpecLog here:http://www.marcusoft.net/2011/02/specification-by-example-with.html and their main site is here: http://www.speclog.net/

I hope this answers you question

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough - I need a document with test cases (which should be extracted from features files), similar like [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_TUs17IBrSL4/SIha2xapDpI/AAAAAAAAADI/X_ywxW20wRs/s1600-h/screenshot_test_case_example.png). SpecLog has nice features but not exactly what I need.